# Azure DevOps Release Pipelines: Failed to download the template parameters file from the given path

Tags: azure-devops

I am deploying ARm template with 'Azure Resource Group Deployment' template and getting an error at release 'Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern'

Getting below warning at override template parameters, however, I have already selected them from the build.

'Warning: Failed to download the template parameters file from the given path '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mybuild-CI' with the following error: The item mybuild-CI could not be found.'

tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/azure/deploy-provision-azure-vm?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mybuild-CI'` is not a file. You need to specify a path to a parameters JSON file.

If there's no JSON file and you want to only provide override values, then leave the field for parameters file blank.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mybuild-CI' is not a file but it is only allowing to select the root build path. it is not allowing to drill down for release but the same arm template is working for build.

Comment: Then type in the rest of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to publish your artifacts

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifacts to drop'
  inputs:
  ArtifactName: 'ARMTemplates'
  PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DevOps-CI/ArmTemplates'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()